# Restart lvmetad service in Linux / Centos / cPanel

Tags: linux, centos, cpanel, restart, whm

I have CentOS 7 with cPanel

Logged in as root in Centos via console: /bin/needs-restarting

display that:
**/usr/sbin/lvmetad -f** need to be restarted(to avoid restarting whole system).

In documentation provided by RedHat regarding to: [The Metadata Daemon(lvmetad)](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Logical_Volume_Manager_Administration/metadatadaemon.html)

I do not find how the metadata caching daemon for LVM can be restarted separatly.

**Q.:** How to restart lvmetad service in Linux / Centos via command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The service is called `lvm2-lvmetad`, as it says in the Red Hat documentation:

> Start the daemon through the `lvm2-lvmetad` service"

You can use `systemctl restart lvm2-lvmetad.service` to restart it.

Comment: Thank you @tongpu! Maybe the service name "lvm2-lvmetad" misled me. However, in my opinion Red Hat documentation must be rebuilded from scratch(search not present on page) even search inside browser didn't find the word "restart".
Thanks to @nixCraft too for retweet my tweet, helped me to recive fast this answer.